# How to use the following command in Jenkins pipeline/Linux

Tags: linux, jenkins

**sed -i 's/foo/bar/gI' cloudformation.yml**

Instead of foo, I'd like it to be the previous build number in Jenkins ${env.BUILD_ID)-1   ,
and bar =  the current build number in jenkins = ${env.BUILD_ID}

So if currently I'm on build 133, jenkins/linux will look for the number 132 in my cloudformation file, and will replace it with 133, and so on.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see all global variables at https://you-jenkins-url/pipeline-syntax/globals. Within a stage directive, add the below.

```
stage('Change-BuildID') {
   steps {
      env.previousBuildID = currentBuild.previousBuild.number
         sh "sed -i \'s/${BUILD_ID}/${env.previousBuildID}/g\' cloudformation.yml"
         }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, vijay